# UI.bootstrap.modal wont open when using latest versions of libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to do this under ASP.NET MVC 5 Visual Studio 2013, with the latest nuget libraries.
AngularJS Core 1.3.8
AngularJS UI Bootstrap 0.12.0
Bootstrap 3.3.1
jQuery 2.1.3

Important files:
App.js

```
var deviceModule = angular.module("devicesModule", ["ui.bootstrap"]);
var app = angular.module("dxuWebApp", ["devicesModule"]);
```

DeviceController.js

```
deviceModule.controller("DevicesController", function ($scope, deviceService, $modal) {
    $scope.devices = [];

    function init() {
        $scope.devices = deviceService.getDevices();
    }

    init();

    $scope.addDevice = function(size) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "newDeviceTemplate.html",
            controller: "NewDeviceModelController",
            size: size
        });

        modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
            alert('yep');
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (newDevice) {
            deviceService.postDevice(newDevice);
        }, function () {

        });

    }
});

deviceModule.controller("NewDeviceModelController", function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close({ name: newDevice.name });
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
    };

});
```

newDeviceTemplate.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h2>New Device</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newDevice.name" />
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div data-ng-app="dxuWebApp" data-ng-controller="DevicesController">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Devices <a data-ng-click="addDevice()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li data-ng-repeat="device in devices | orderBy: 'name'">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="device">
                            <div class="deviceImage">
                                @*<img alt="device image"/>*@
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>

                            </div>
                            <div class="deviceName">
                                {{device.name | uppercase}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dxuWebApp")
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="newDevice.html">        
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2>New Device</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newDevice.name" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
}
```

The references to both ui-bootstrap and ui-bootstrap.tpls are in the _layout page.

I was hoping that when I clicked

```
<a data-ng-click="addDevice()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">
```

AngularJs magic would happen and I would get a modal on the screen, but nothing happens, no errors or anything like that.
I did put a break point on `deviceController.addDevice()` and it hit that point and goes through, nothing appear on the screen.

So what wrong with my code?

Comment: Where is this `newDeviceTemplate.html` defined?

Comment: I have tried 2 different ways, I have on the script tag, as newDevice.html, and also I have a separate file, that is located on the same folder as the jscript for simplification (ideally I want it in the "views" folder)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

I am using MVC 5.0 with AngularJS so the reason it wasn't working ( I was getting a 404 not able to find the modal.html.) was I didn't create a route in the controller for the modal.html or map a view to the controller with the same name as the route.

After properly setting up the Controller and the View it worked.

Sorry there is no code for this since it was just a problem following the MVC process.